# As a new learner, where should I begin learning piano?

Tags: beginner

As a new piano learner, what should I learn first (I don't have any musical knowledge, except I can read sheet music but not good)?It would be great if you wrote consecutively or any book that takes from zero.

Comment: There is a post dedicated to this on reddit, you may find it helpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/piano/wiki/faq#wiki_getting_started_as_a_beginner

Comment: It covers a part of my needs but not everything I want.It covers techniques but not theories.It's an incredible resource for improving techniques though, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your goals are, but if you are mainly interested in playing from lead sheets I would recommend ["How to Play the Piano Despite Years of Lessons"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0385142633) by Cannel and Marx which will give you enough theory and practice techniques to start playing from fakebooks.

Definitely watch YouTube videos and if you find a video you like, subscribe to that artist's channel.  But in addition there are [free piano instruction sites online](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-5-sites-for-learning-piano-online/) to check out.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's a fantastic book to get started with :) Yes, I follow some channels on YouTube but the book is more helpful I think

Answer (score 0):

Start learning piano while sitting next to a piano teacher.  It isn't really something you can teach yourself from a book.

Comment: I would like to but there is almost no piano teachers near where I live.I have to travel a lot to get a teacher but I can't, I'm still studying.So I want to learn some basics and some basic techinques until I find a teacher.

Comment: You can't teach yourself from a book, but you can teach yourself from a book, videos, and, above all, a piano! I did so and passed an audition that was made in exceptional cases for those who don't have their Grade 10 Royal Conservatory certificate. Of course, my technique is idiosyncratic, and I'm actually looking into lessons now to iron some of the unevenness out, but I'd say I learned how to play piano. Supplementary aids: about a year of lessons when I was 6 or 7 (?) from which my parents pulled me out because I made no progress + theory/recorder/trumpet at school till I was 14.

Comment: @Rutrasss just learn from youtube videos. the last 10 years is probably the only time in humanity this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing some of [these](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons) lessons to teach yourself basic music theory. I would start with learning note rhythms and how to read music notation.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTUtqcDkzw7bisadh6AOx5w) is a good YouTube channel about music theory without making it to boring and [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNBiLBQrKrnvwcVRD5fS8aA) one is probably my favorite out of all. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0739015575) is what I did when I was first learning music notation, these flash cards will teach you the basics.

I also like to carry around [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1598062298) and [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0882847309) just in case I run into anything that is not familiar to me.

Good Luck, and remember that Practice makes Perfect!